# Should I call my code a game engine?

Tags: javascript, game-engine

I'm thinking about writing some code in JavaScript which I can use in my games. It will be extremely simple just providing thinks like a game loop, rendering and user input. It won't have an interface where you type in your code, or build maps. Can I call this code a game engine?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_engine

Comment: Maybe this wiki article can help you with your decision: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_engine

Comment: You can call it a tree aswell. But seriously: What you call your code is your own decision. Do you want to code a game engine? Call it a game engine! Do you want to code a helper which will help people code games? Call it helper fpr game developers. Call it whatever you'd like to.

Comment: You may get a better response posting your question here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ but I think it's too vague and not particularly constructive and will likely be closed.

Comment: Depends who you're selling to. The name is marketing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably call it a Game Framework, as it helps people get up an running. Maybe it's missing a few things to be called an engine.

Comment: what things will make it a game engine?

Comment: does it handle physics, graphics, networking, loading levels, models etc.

Answer (score 0):

this depends on your definition of a game engine. Usually, game engines are more specific, providing both a physics engine and a rendering engine. Although wikipedia is not all-mighty, your code is not a game engine according to [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_engine)